# HEAD detached from a previous version

Tags: git, github

I wanted to go to a previous version, then I did

```
git checkout 577ba726a9e21a62d33f2f1837ccb0a47ee434b4

git commit -m "revert"
```

Then I realise that it does not work as what I expected: the code in the github webpage is not what was in `577ba726a9e21a62d33f2f1837ccb0a47ee434b4`. So I manually modified the whole code as what was in `577ba726a9e21a62d33f2f1837ccb0a47ee434b4`. Then I did

```
git add .
git commit -m "m"
git push -u origin master
git pull origin master
```

But it gives me

```
HEAD detached from 577ba72
nothing to commit, working tree clean
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Everything up-to-date
From https://github.com/chengtie/funfun
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

And the code in my local disk is NOT the code in the github page.

How could I align these two places? I am totally lost...

Comment: I'm not going to close this right away as a duplicate (since it's not clear to me what you are concerned about *right now*), but see https://stackoverflow.com/q/4114095/1256452 for the answer to the original problem you were describing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in a "detached HEAD" state because you do not have a local branch which points to 577ba726a9e21a62d33f2f1837ccb0a47ee434b4. You could create one however with:

```
git checkout -b saveSpot
```

This will take you out of the detached state.

--

If you want your `master` branch to point to a particular commit you can use the `reset` command like this:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard 577ba726a9e21a62d33f2f1837ccb0a47ee434b4
git push -f origin master
```

**But a warning**: This will overwrite your master branch, hence the `-f` which is to "force" a push. So make sure your teammates are aware of what's going on before you push.

Comment: Now I just want my local code to override what is in github, and get the control of `master` back... What should I do?

Comment: If you want your local code to override what is in GitHub then following the push command I have above should accomplish that.